# Missing Android 5.0 (SDK 20) Android Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Android 5.0 (SDK 20) is missing from the system images list in Android Studio 4.0. How to get it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried many different devices, but SDK 20 and 21 is not available anywhere :/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools - SDK manager - System settings - Android SDK find the API your looking for click on the box then that should show a download symbol next to it click it then press OK, should ask if you want to download it.

Answer (score 3):

SDK 20 is not something you need to be concerned about for 5.0 it's a version of Kitkat for android Wear products, as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms#4.4):

> Android 4.4W (API level 20)
> This version makes KitKat available for Android Wear.